# Heatmap using lines in shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, heat-map, openrouteservice

I used openrouteservice to produce routes from many points to one point. I would like to add some sort of heatmap scheme to this - supposedly blue for least popular routes and red for routes with most footfall where multiple routes overlap. Is there a way of doing this in QGIS?

Comment: You could split your routes at the vertices and then sum up the "stepcount" per segment  of your routes.

Answer (score 1):

The [line density tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#line-density) in the interpolation toolset might work, especially if you use a small raster cell size.

If each route is a different file you could do [spatial join](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html) with a summation added.  Then symbolize off of the sum.